# Dynamically set topic name and Kafka Brokers in PublishKafka2_0 processor in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using the PublishKafka processor in nifi to publish JSON data in Kafka. I want to set Kafka Server and topic name details from attribute values. I am not able to do this. It's giving the below error

> PublishKafka_2_0[id=2cb333e9-5fd6-1254-a10c-d1084b230d03] Processing
> halted: yielding [1 sec]: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException:
> Failed to construct kafka producer
>
> - Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers .

Only hardcoded values of the Kafka server and the topic name is working.

Am I missing something? Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Check https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Parameters

Comment: Inside the data of attributes, I have the Kafka Information Like bootstrap server details and topic name. How can I change the Kafka Broker and topic name for every data in Nifi parameters